# Why is subshell created by background control operator (&) not displayed under pstree

Tags: bash, job-control, jobs, subshell

I understand that when I run `exit` it terminates my current shell because `exit` command run in the same shell. I also understand that when I run `exit &` then original shell will not terminate because `&` ensures that the command is run in sub-shell resulting that `exit` will terminate this sub-shell and return back to original shell. But what I do not understand is why commands with and without `&` looks exactly the same under `pstree`, in this case `sleep 10` and `sleep 10 &`. 4669 is the PID of bash under which first `sleep 10` and then `sleep 10 &` were issued and following output was obtained from another shell instance during this time:

```
# version without &
$ pstree 4669
bash(4669)───sleep(6345)

# version with &
$ pstree 4669
bash(4669)───sleep(6364)
```

Should't the version with `&` contain one more spawned sub-shell (e.g. in this case with PID 5555), like this one?

```
bash(4669)───bash(5555)───sleep(6364)
```

PS: Following code was omitted from output of `pstree` beginning for better readability:

```
systemd(1)───slim(1009)───ck-launch-sessi(1370)───openbox(1551)───/usr/bin/termin(4510)───bash(4518)───screen(4667)───screen(4668)───
```

Comment: I usually check the *Related* questions for possible duplicates (then flag them) before answering a question. In this case, I strongly disagree that this is a duplicate since it focuses on commands being run in the background – not enclosed in parentheses. This question is informative, thought-provoking and offers a greater insight into an aspect of subshells not covered in the *“duplicate”*; IMO, this deserves more attention (and upvotes). BTW, I’ve extended and further clarified my answer to incorporate suggestions from the comments (and deleted my own comments to minimise the clutter).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Until I started answering this question, I hadn’t realised that using the `&` *control operator* to run a *job* in the background starts a subshell.  Subshells are created when commands are wrapped in parentheses or form part of a pipeline (each command in a pipeline is executed in its own subshell).

The [Lists of Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Lists.html) section of the Bash manual (*thanks jimmij*) states:

> If a command is terminated by the control operator ‘&’, the shell executes
>   the command asynchronously in a subshell. This is known as executing the
>   command in the *background*. The shell does not wait for the command to
>   finish, and the return status is 0 (true).

As I understand it, when you run `sleep 10 &` the shell [fork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call))s to create a new child process (a copy of itself) and then immediately [exec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exec_%28computing%29)s to replace this child process with code from the external command (`sleep`).  This is similar to what happens when a command is run as normal (in the foreground). See the [Fork–exec Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork%E2%80%93exec) for a short overview of this mechanism.

I couldn’t understand why Bash would run backgrounded commands in a subshell but it makes sense if you also want to be able to run shell builtins such as `exit` or `echo` to be run in the background (not just external commands).

When it’s a shell builtin that’s being run in the background, the `fork` happens (resulting in a subshell) without an `exec` call to replace itself with an external command.  Running the following commands shows that when the `echo` command is wrapped in curly braces and run in the background (with the `&`), a subshell is indeed created:

```
$ { echo $BASH_SUBSHELL $BASHPID; }
0 21516
$ { echo $BASH_SUBSHELL $BASHPID; } &
[1] 22064
$ 1 22064
```

In the above example, I wrapped the `echo` command in curly braces to avoid `BASH_SUBSHELL` being expanded by the current shell; curly braces are used to group commands together without using a subshell. The second version of the command (ending with the `&` control operator) clearly demonstrates that terminating the command with the ampersand has resulted in a subshell (with a new PID) being created to execute the `echo` builtin. *(I’m probably simplifying the shell’s behaviour here. See mikeserv’s comment.)*

I would never have thought of running `exit &` and had I not read your question, I would have expected the current shell to quit. Knowing now that such commands are run in a subshell, your explanation that it’s the subshell which exits makes sense.

---

*“Why is subshell created by background control operator (&) not displayed under pstree”*

As mentioned above, when you run `sleep 10 &`, Bash forks itself to create the subshell but since `sleep` is an external command, it calls the `exec()` system call which immediately replaces the Bash code and data in the child process with a running copy of the `sleep` program. By the time you run `pstree`, the `exec` call will already have completed and the child process will now have the name “*sleep*”.

---

While away from my computer, I tried to think of a way of keeping the subshell running long enough for the subshell to be displayed by `pstree`. I figured we could run the command through the `time` builtin:

```
$ time sleep 11 &
[2] 4502
$ pstree -p 26793
bash(26793)─┬─bash(4502)───sleep(4503)
            └─pstree(4504)
```

Here, the Bash shell (26793) forks to create a subshell (4502) in order to execute the command in the background. This subshell runs its own `time` builtin command which, in turn, forks (to create a new process with PID 4503) and execs to run the external `sleep` command.

---

Using [named pipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe), *jimmij* came up with a clever way to keep the subshell created to run `exit` alive long enough for it to be displayed by `pstree`:

```
$ mkfifo file
$ exit <file &
[2] 6413
$ pstree -p 26793
bash(26793)─┬─bash(6413)
            └─pstree(6414)
$ echo > file
$ jobs
[2]-  Done    exit < file
```

Redirecting `stdin` from a named pipe is clever as it causes the subshell to block until it receives input from the named pipe.  Later, redirecting the output of `echo` (without any arguments) writes a newline character to the named pipe which unblocks the subshell process which, in turn, runs the `exit` builtin command.

---

Similarly, for the `sleep` command:

```
$ mkfifo named_pipe
$ sleep 11 < named_pipe &
[1] 6600
$ pstree -p 26793
bash(26793)─┬─bash(6600)
            └─pstree(6603)
```

Here we see that the subshell created to run the command in the background has a PID of `6600`. Next, we unblock the process by writing a newline character to the pipe:

```
$ echo > named_pipe
```

The subshell then `exec`s to run the `sleep` command.

```
$ pstree -p 26793
bash(26793)─┬─pstree(6607)
            └─sleep(6600)
```

After the `exec()` call, we can see that the child process (`6600`) is now running the `sleep` program.

Comment: My premise is based on this article: "This trailing ampersand directs the shell to run the command in the background, that is, it is forked and run in a separate sub-shell, as a job, asynchronously." http://bashitout.com/2013/05/18/Ampersands-on-the-command-line.html

Comment: `&` always causes the shell to fork. The forked shell process either handles the command itself (which is the case with `exit`), or makes a system call to (some form of) `exec` to replace itself with the given command.

Comment: I assume the reason that `exit` starts a subshell is that it is a shell builtin. The shell has to create a new process. But what process should that be if there is no external command to run? Technically this may the same like a normal subshell but "semantically" it seems slightly different. You don't call a subshell but the technical circumstances enforce a subshell.

Comment: Bash manual states it clearly: `If a command is terminated by the control operator &, the shell executes the command
       in the background in a subshell.  The shell does not wait for the command to finish, and the return status is 0.` Thus subshell is always created with `&` and one can see this with `echo "$$ $BASHPID" &`.

Comment: There are a lot of factors besides which affect the shell's behavior here. For example active `trap`s will preclude an implicit `exec` , often trailing newlines do also, or i/o attachments associated w/ complex commands *(like your `{ echo; }&` thing)*. Basically if there is any chance of the shell having to do something else it probably shouldn't `exec`. use `PS4=\$$\ + "$0" -cx 'test cases' to more simply test.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan "when you run sleep 10 & the shell forks to create a new child process (a copy of itself) and then immediately execs to replace this child process with code from the sleep command." So in theory if you are not fast enough you cannot see created sub-shell? "Having read Chepner’s comment, it seems that when it’s a shell builtin that’s being run in the background, the fork happens without the exec." Sorry I did not still catch it, even if `exit` would be executed with `exec` the situation will be exactly the same (sub-shell will terminate and original persists) am I wrong?

Comment: @Wakan Tanka `cmd &` is grosso modo equivalent (from the subshells point of view) of `bash -c 'cmd'`. If there is only one command bash replace itself with it (if thats external command), otherwise stays. Obviously you are not fast enough to see subshell in the pstree if cmd is builtin, but e.g. run `mkfifo file`, and then after `exit<file &` watch pstree.

Comment: @Anthony Geoghegan You can see how sleep replaces bash in the same manner as I previously wrote. `mkdir file` and then `sleep 10 <file &` and observe pstree in the other terminal. See the `bash` with some pid? Now run `echo foo >file` (still in some other terminal) and again pstree. See the `sleep` with the same pid as previously bash had?

Comment: @WakanTanka - you can catch the subshell before its replaced by explicitly tracking its PID. `bash -c cmd` is not equivalent to `cmd &` in that `bash -c` gets its own `$$` while `&` doesn't. `alias 'tracepid=PS4='\''$0 -- $* : $PPID.$$ + '\'' sh -cx '\''"$0" "$@"'\'' '`. You can call up any simple command with that alias and it will always print the commands PID and its args to stderr *before* the command is run. stick that inside your `&` subshells to the subshell's PIDs in realtime *and* to get the `&` subshell's PID's as you go. `tracepid sleep 10 &` for example.

Comment: @HaukeLaging "But what process should that be if there is no external command to run?" A fork *always* creates a copy of the current process; there's no such thing as a process without a command. The shell starts any external command by forking, and the new copy of the shell then executes `exec` to replace itself with the new command.

Comment: @Anthony Geoghegan: Interesting answer.  A quick note: *reading* from a pipe (named or otherwise) waits for input to be available.  (Or for the pipe to be closed; EOF acts like input in this context.)  But `sleep 11 < named_pipe` doesn’t *read* from the pipe, it only ***opens it** for reading*, because `sleep` doesn’t read from stdin.  An *open for reading* on a named pipe blocks only until somebody ***opens the fifo for writing***.  So, you could replace `echo > named_pipe` with `: > named_pipe` (using the no-op command, **`:`**) or even, in some shells, `> named_pipe` (using a null command).

Comment: Thanks @G-Man for the very clear explanation of pipes and blocking (great use of Markdown for adding appropriate emphasis). I didn't realise that a FIFO only has to be opened (for writing) to unblock a process that has it opened for reading. This answer could do with a rewrite and when I find the time, I'll incorporate that information into it.